# Get IPaddress of virtual machine

Tags: ip-address, hypervisor, microsoft-bits

How to transfer files using BITs protocol if I know of only Ip address of target machine. does BITs work with such. like according to theory microsoft uses BITS to update computer so it must be working with ipaddresses as well. how does it done.

start BITS-Transfer c:\abc.jpg  \192.168.14.27\xyz\

this is returning error like bits shouldnt have any null parameter ....th sseond ipaddress parameter is null according to it. this machine is also is my same local natework. and i turned of firewall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for getting IP address of virtual machines on HyperV

```
Get-VM | ?{$_.State -eq "Running"} |  Get-VMNetworkAdapter | Select VMName, IPAddresses
```

and to start bits transfer using ip address is..

```
  Start-BitsTransfer -Source D:\abc.exe -Destination //ipaddress_target/C$/XE.exe -TransferType Upload
```